# Rails: AJAX Form not passing parameter on heroku but working locally

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm unable to get a AJAX form to work on Heroku even though it works locally. 
you can check out the heroku app here -

https://mysterious-wildwood-6447.herokuapp.com/

(The form is the new subreddit form located on the right of the screen)

The form code in the view (its a partial) -

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/subreddits" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="input-small" name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
</div>
<div class="form-group sr-title">
    <input class="form-control input-small subreddit_title_field" placeholder="Create new subreddit" type="text" name="subreddit[title]" id="subreddit_title">
</div> <button type="submit" name="commit" class="btn btn-default new-subreddit">Submit</button>
```

the code in the respective controller -

```
def create
    p params[:subreddit_title]
    @subreddit = Subreddit.new(title: params[:subreddit_title].downcase)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subreddit.save
        format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
      else
        @error = @subreddit.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        format.js { render 'error.js.erb' }
      end
    end
  end
```

the javascript application code snippet (in application.js)-

```
$('.new-subreddit').on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $('.subreddit_title_field').val();
            var values = {
                subreddit_title: form_data,
            }
            var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                url: '/subreddits',
                type: 'POST', // GET, PUT, DELETE
                data: values,
            });
   });
```

the output locally for "bridges" as a form input (which works)-

tarted POST "/subreddits" for ::1 at 2015-05-09 11:55:52 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (6.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by SubredditsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"subreddit_title"=>"bridges"}
"bridges"
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Subreddit Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subreddits" WHERE "subreddits"."title" = 'bridges' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "subreddits" ("title", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "bridges"], ["created_at", "2015-05-09 06:25:53.054220"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-09 06:25:53.054220"]]
   (12.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered subreddits/create.js.erb (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 93ms (Views: 20.4ms | ActiveRecord: 23.4ms)

the output from heroku logs -

2015-05-09T06:02:56.196766+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/subreddits" for 180.151.86.227 at 2015-05-09 06:02:56 +0000
2015-05-09T06:02:56.200751+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SubredditsController#create as */*
2015-05-09T06:02:56.203206+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-05-09T06:02:56.203210+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass):
2015-05-09T06:02:56.203212+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/subreddits_controller.rb:8:in`create'